# How to create string from uint8[] in Vala?

Tags: string, buffer, vala

I am doing async reads from a [DataInputStream](https://valadoc.org/gio-2.0/GLib.DataInputStream.html) filling a buffer with bytes.

```cs
uint8[] buffer = new uint8[4096];
size_t bytes = 0;
bool success = false;

do
{
  success = yield process.get_stdout_pipe().read_all_async(
    buffer,
    GLib.Priority.LOW, 
    null, 
    out bytes
  );
{
while(success && bytes > 0);
```

I want to combine the data into a string. I had a look at [StringBuilder](https://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.StringBuilder.html) but that has no function to append any arrays.

What is the best approach to build a string while async reading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just cast `uint8[]` to `string` anytime.
Code:

```
uint8[] chars = {31,32,33,34,35,36,37};
print(@"$((string) chars)\n");
```

Output:

```
!"#$%
```

Comment: A string in C (and Vala) is zero terminated. As long as the buffer is zero terminated this will work fine.

Comment: This works. As the length is known, I look for a way where the length is considered like `printf(@"%.*s\n", bytes, (string) buffer)` I feel like StringBuilder is missing an essential feature here.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the `print` solution a simple loop and using [`append_c`](https://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.StringBuilder.append_c.html) from the `StringBuilder` in a loop works. Just append every byte till the end of array

```cs
var builder = new StringBuilder(buffer.length);
for(int i=0; i<buffer.length; i++ {
  builder.append_c(buffer[i]);
}
```